# Vue Material Tabs not showing content

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

The program must shows the page when that is selected from tab using Vue Material Tab. I've configured routes and installed dependencies but when I click on the tab not is showed. The code have two Vue components to test two screens content. The ideia is show a row like toolbar at top of view and populate it with tabs. The two screens are `Menu` and `Home`.

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
     <md-tabs md-sync-route>
       <md-tab id="tab-home" md-label="Home" to="/components/Home" exact></md-tab>
       <md-tab id="tab-pages" md-label="Pages" to="/components/Menu"></md-tab>
     </md-tabs>
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
   name: 'App',
  }
</script>
```

**index.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Home from '@/components/Home'
import Menu from '@/components/Menu'

import VueMaterial from 'vue-material'
import 'vue-material/dist/vue-material.min.css'
import 'vue-material/dist/theme/default.css'

Vue.use(VueMaterial)
Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'Home',
            component: Home
        },
        {
            path: '/Home',
            name: 'Home',
            component: Home
        },
        {
            path: '/Menu',
            name: 'Menu',
            component: Menu
        },
    ]
})
```

**Menu.vue**

```
<template>
   <div>
       <h1>Menu</h1>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'Menu'
    }
</script>
```

**Home.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Home</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'Home',
  }
</script>
```

Comment: the "to" property in the md-tab needs to send you to the route , so it needs to be 
"/Home" and "/Menu" to match the entries you created in your router, then the router will be the one creating the components there

Comment: Yes, it's worked

Comment: You should not have 2 different routes with same name, use [redirect or alias](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/redirect-and-alias.html#redirect-and-alias)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo don't have routes with path `/components/Home` and `/components/Menu` in your router config. So provide correct path's.

```
<md-tab id="tab-home" md-label="Home" to="/Home" exact></md-tab>
<md-tab id="tab-pages" md-label="Pages" to="/Menu"></md-tab>
```